# The edge color of the histogram is not changing even though I declared it

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I can't change the border color even though I declared it as black.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10), tight_layout = True, edgecolor = 'black')
plt.title('Distribution of Item Type')
plt.xlabel('Item Type')


plt.hist(BigMart_Data_Encoded['Item_Type'],bins = 15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the `edgecolor` parameter inside the `.hist()` function instead of figure:

```py
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10), tight_layout = True)
plt.title('Distribution of Item Type')
plt.xlabel('Item Type')


plt.hist(BigMart_Data_Encoded['Item_Type'],bins=15, edgecolor='black')
```